# Grid layout with different height items (React Native)

Tags: gridview, react-native

Any idea for implementing a grid layout like the following image. 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on the data you are going to display. I guess this is an infinite list which loads more items on scroll down. If that's the case you need to put 3 `ListView`-s inside a `ScrollView`

The markup will look like this:

```html
<View style={styles.wrapper}>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
        <ListView 
            contentContainerStyle={styles.list} 
            dataSource={this.state.dataSourceColumn1}
        />
        <ListView 
            contentContainerStyle={styles.list} 
            dataSource={this.state.dataSourceColumn2}
        />
        <ListView 
            contentContainerStyle={styles.list} 
            dataSource={this.state.dataSourceColumn3}
        />
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Wrapper `View` will help you stretch the block to fit the entire area. From the styling point of view you can resolve the task with flexbox:

```js
wrapper: {
    flex: 1
},
container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingHorizontal: 5
},
list: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 5
}
```

The trick is that we treat every column as a row inside the container. Play around with paddings and `alignItems` styling to achieve consistent spacing.

Now the tricky part is to handle the `dataSource` properly. The idea is to have 3 `dataSource`-s in the component state. This way whenever the data has been fetched, you'll have to go over it manually and split into three sources.

Note that the handy `onEndReached` that comes with the `ListView` won't be available here, so you'll have to catch the user reaching the end of the `ScrollView` in order to know when new fetch is required. But that's a different question which I believe has already been answered elsewhere.

In case the grid is finite and you don't need to throw more items into it, things are simpler. Just split the data the way described above and use 3 `View`-s with nested items instead of the `ListView`-s. The reasoning behind that is that `ListView` comes with a way to set a `rowHasChanged` condition, which improves performance by never rendering the unchanged list items. You don't really need that if the list is finite.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this with a single list? i.e. using a single movement gesture to spin all 3 columns?

Comment: @DrorBar The lists are wrapped in a ScrollView, so all 3 columns would be scrolled by a single gesture. The user would basically be swiping the ScrollView. As an update I suggest using `FlatList`-s rather than `ListView`-s, I haven't tried that, but maybe you'd need to prevent individual `FlatList`-s from scrolling if columns are scrolled individually.

Comment: I tried to recreate your suggestion with FlatList. I needed to give each FlatList the prop pointerEvents="none" otherwise it would scroll each list individually. However, then I was having the issue where scrolling the ScrollView would not reveal more of the FlatLists. So I'm not sure this actually works... unless you know something that I don't :)

Comment: I was able to come up with a different solution [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504466/react-native-flatlist-with-dynamic-height-children/55191806#55191806).